# MMC reader driver for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I have recently installed windows 8 in my computer and i recieve the following notification:
"solve a problem with ENE PCI Secure Digital /MMC Card Reader Controller".

I couldn't find any driver of this online . It's a 6 years old laptop. Windows 8 run normally but i have a problem with istalling and updating apps in the app store. When an app is downloading, procedure stops and a message "This app couldn't be installed.Please try again" appears.
Where can i find this driver or is there any other solution to my app problem?

(Laptop Turbo-X M67SRU,clevo)

Comment: Advice for the future: please write titles that are immediate to understand for others without reading the full question. Your question is about a MMC reader driver, so be it and clearly say that in title! :) Welcome to superuser anyway

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1) you don have the driver. Are you using SD / MMC on your laptop ? If so look at ENE's website

2) you cannot install windows Store App. The message says nothing. Have you even been able to install any apps ?

Comment: 1)no, i don't use.
2)i can't istall any app or open.

Answer (score 0):

which versions of X86 or x64 windows8 are you using? Did you try windows 7 driver?
you can download latest driver from [here.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7424772/ENE%20Card%20Reader.rar)

Comment: i'm using x86. I downloaded this driver but it finds no device to update. I did a windows reset but now it crashes all the time with dpc watch dog violation error. i think I go back to Vista..

Comment: at lease switch back to 7 , because it's 100% better than vista

Comment: i know..finally i've got ubuntu 11.10 and i'm really happy!Thank you for your answers.